# Best Java practice for making a class that contains lists of objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I am making a simple command line Java application. It allows user to create instances of class car by going trough command line menu and inputing the car data. When a user creates a car I want to add it to an arraylist of cars. I don't want to keep the list in my main class.

What I am planning to do is make an abstract class called Container that have arraylist of cars in it. I'm planning to extend the app to also include the creaton of airplanes, so I would also add an arraylist of airplanes in Container class.

Is this approach ok? Is there some approach that is more commonly used?

Comment: In your Car class, you can juste put a static ArrayList<Car> in which you put every new car... And you will do the same for planes and others.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class level variable for list and use that, there is not benefit of creating an abstract class for that .

```
class Car
{
  private static List list = new ArrayList();
  public static void main(String ...args)
  {
    // Your Code goes here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea.  Create another class to hold the lists.  I called this class Inventory, but you can give the class a more meaningful name.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Inventory {

    private List<Car> cars;
    private List<Airplane> aitplanes;

    public Inventory() {
        this.cars = new ArrayList<>();
        this.airplanes = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public List<Airplane> getAitplanes() {
        return aitplanes;
    }

    public void addCar(Car car) {
        cars.add(car);
    }

    public void addAirplane(Airplane airplane) {
        airplanes.add(airplane);
    }
}
```